# How can I allow null values in my Elasticsearch results?

Tags: null, elasticsearch, match, minimum

I'm using Elasticsearch to search for records in a database. The records have a field for `start_date` and `end_date`, and the user is able to specify the date range they want to check. The start and end dates of the record must both be within the specified date range. However, some of the records only have a start_date, so the end_date field is null. I want these records to be returned as well, so long as the start_date is within the range.

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 20,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "last_name": {
              "query": "Beach",
              "boost": 1.0,
              "analyzer": "standard",
              "fuzziness": 2.0
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "range": {
            "start_date.year": {
              "gte": "1800",
              "lte": 1900
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "end_date.year": {
              "gte": "1800",
              "lte": 1900
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

The problem is that, because only one of the date fields needs to match, when I DO have a record with both a `start_date` and an `end_date`, one of them may be out of range. How can I require that both the `start_date` and `end_date` are within range, but allow the `start_date` or `end_date` value to be null?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
{
 "from" : 0,
 "size" : 20,
 "query" : {
  "bool" : {
   "must" : [{
     "match" : {
      "last_name" : {
       "query" : "Beach",
       "boost" : 1.0,
       "analyzer" : "standard",
       "fuzziness" : 2.0
      }
     }
    }
   ],
   "should" : [{
     "bool" : {
      "must" : [{
        "range" : {
         "start_date.year" : {
          "gte" : "1800",
          "lte" : 1900
         }
        }
       }, {
        "range" : {
         "end_date.year" : {
          "gte" : "1800",
          "lte" : 1900
         }
        }
       }
      ]
     }
    }, {
     "bool" : {
      "must" : [{
        "range" : {
         "start_date.year" : {
          "gte" : "1800",
          "lte" : 1900
         }
        }
       }, {
        "constant_score" : {
         "filter" : {
          "missing" : {
           "field" : "end_date.year"
          }
         }
        }
       }
      ]
     }
    }, {
     "bool" : {
      "must" : [{
        "range" : {
         "end_date.year" : {
          "gte" : "1800",
          "lte" : 1900
         }
        }
       }, {
        "constant_score" : {
         "filter" : {
          "missing" : {
           "field" : "start_date.year"
          }
         }
        }
       }
      ]
     }
    }
   ],
   "minimum_should_match" : 1
  }
 }
}
```

The idea is to create 3 possible cases: either both start date and end date are in range, or start date is in range and no end date, or end date in range and no start date.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by putting the date fields in an OR filter, so that after the rest of the query body, the results are filtered by start_date OR end_date.

I suppose this may cause bugs if both fields exist but one of them is out of range, in which case Rotem Hermon's answer sounds like a good idea. For now this has solved the issue though.